# Does the def keyword uses more space in Groovy?

Tags: performance, groovy

The `def`-keyword used to declare variables and methods can be used instead of the explicit type of an object or method. 
Is the use of the `def`-keyword advisable? Does it use more memory? Should it be avoided when the exact type is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

def is just like Object. The amount of memory it will or will not use depends on the value of the variable.

Whether to use it or not is more about safety of your code rather then performance. If you know you will be dealing with String or int only, define your variable as such. If you have absolutely no clue what the type might be (or you don't care because you are just putting together quick-execute-and-throw-away script) it's fine to go with def.

There's also few other subtle differences about scope of vars, but for that you better read [groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22)

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

`def` is a declaration for a variable with dynamic typing. You are stating you don't care about the type. It **is** more idiomatic Groovy.

It enables you to use flow typing. This will work:

```
def d = new Date()
d = "echo"
```

Whereas this will fails with a `GroovyCastException`:

```
Date d = new Date()
d = "echo"
```

And flow typing works under `@TypeChecked`:

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
def test() { 
  def d = new Date()
  d.year
  d = "echo"
  d.toUpperCase()
}
```

All Groovy method calls will go through the MOP. If there is a bottleneck, it *may be* be this guy, and not the reference type you use. If performance is a concern, consider using `@CompileStatic` when you detect slower methods and/or classes.